# Managing user sessions and JWTs with Golang Gorilla Sessions package

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, jwt, gorilla

I'm writing a web app which allows users to login using multiple IDPs (Google, Yahoo, Microsoft), and then allowing them to persist/retrieve data managed by my Golang server.

I wanted to outline my approach to see if my understanding of JWTs and managing user sessions is accurate, and clarify a few things related to secure session management.

I am using Gorilla Mux for routing, Gorilla Sessions for managing user sessions, and Gorilla CSRF for CSRF validation. I am also configuring the Gorilla Session store with a secure key and setting:

```
  var sessionStore = sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte(os.Getenv("SESSION_AUTH_KEY")))

  . . .
  sessionStore.Options.HttpOnly = true
  sessionStore.Options.Secure = true
```

As per my understanding, `HttpOnly` and `Secure` should prevent the cookies being read by any form of client-side access (I have HTTPS configured).

For authentication, I am using Firebase to obtain the JWT. Here is a high-level flow:

1. User clicks on the relevant IDP's Login button, which prompts them to log in with the relevant credentials via Firebase, which returns a JWT token to my client JS app upon a authentication.
2. The client app POSTs this JWT (ID token returned by firebase) to my Golang webserver (e.g, to a `/login` endpoint)
3. The Golang web server handler for `/login` uses the Firebase Admin SDK to verify the JWT from the request, and then sets up the session:

```
func LoginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        .  .  .
        // 'idToken' is the JWT from the request
        // 'client' is an instance of auth.Client using the Firebase admin SDK
        //
        decodedToken, err := client.VerifyIDToken(context.Background(), idToken)
    if err != nil {
        . . .
    }

    email := decodedToken.Claims["email"].(string)
    name := decodedToken.Claims["name"].(string)

    var user models.User
    res = globalDb.Where("email = ?", email).Find(&user)

    // User not found; create new user now because this is equivalent to a sign-up.
    //
    if res.RowsAffected == 0 {
        user = models.User{
            Name:    name,
            Email:   email,
        }

        if res = globalDb.Create(&user); res.Error != nil {
            . . .
        }
    } 

    // Create a session for the user.
    //
    session, _ := sessionStore.Get(r, "user-session")

    session.Values["user_id"] = user.ID.String()

    // Save it before we write to the response/return from the handler.
    //
    err = session.Save(r, w)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

        . . .

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
```

4. Subsequent requests validate the user is logged in by checking:

```
func verifyAuthenticationOrWriteError(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (bool, *models.User) {
    session, err := sessionStore.Get(r, "user-session")

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Unauthorized to Access this Page.", http.StatusForbidden)
        return false, nil
    }

    var userId interface{} = session.Values["user_id"]

    if userId == nil {
        http.Error(w, "Unauthorized to Access this Page.", http.StatusForbidden)
        return false, nil
    }

    var user models.User

    // Return the user object.
    //
    if err := globalDb.Find(&user, "id = ?", userId.(string)).Error; err != nil {
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        return false, nil
    }

    return true, &user
}
```

A few things I am still unclear about, which I would appreciate clarity on:

1. I was under the impression that Gorilla Sessions would only write out the session ID in a Cookie to the response. This session ID would be passed back to the server in subsequent requests, which would be used to obtain the current session using `sessionStore.Get()`, and thereby obtain the `session.Values` map from the backing store (in-memory or persistent DB)
   However, it seems that even the `session.Values` map is written out in the cookie. Should this/can this be prevented?
2. I am only utilizing the JWT to validate the login and pull the desired used metadata (email/name), but using the `user.ID` from my Database to identify the current user/verify authentication on subsequent requests via the Session. Should I   be using the JWT as a cookie instead, and if so, what are the benefits of doing this? Firebase docs outline the latter approach: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#go
3. My API endpoints are of the pattern:

```
r.HandleFunc("/user/{user_id}/objects", GetObjects).Methods("GET")
```

The handler for each endpoint (`GetObjects` for e.g), will validate the `user_id` from the request params and match that against the user object obtained by fetching the user corresponding to `session.Values["user_id"]` in Step (4) above.

Is this a safe/standard workflow for securely authenticating users, or am I missing key checks here which could open this up to different methods of session hijacking?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!